# Bootstrap produces inf confidence interval

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, standard-error, relative-risk

I am using bootstrapping to calculate confidence intervals for a risk ratio. In some of the bootstrapped samples, there are no observations of one of the outcomes, leading to the risk ratio being value / 0. Thus, when I try to calculate the SE, I get a NaN value in R, and thus an Inf upper CI.

How should I calculate the standard error and confidence intervals with a risk ratio? I have a very small sample within strata (and need to calculate the risk ratio in the strata.)

Comment: You could try something like Laplace smoothing.  Estimate the mean in each group using $(1 + \sum x_i) / (1 + N)$.  This would ensure a non-zero denominator.  i'm not sure what kind of bias this would impart so you might want to simulate it

Comment: And if you use percentile method?